# Rails - execute JS after a controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `login_controller` which handles user logins.  It uses single sign on - so the login is seemless to the user and they will be redirected to the page they were trying to access (e.g. for example if they had a link bookmarked).

I want to execute a js snippet for analytics.  But I only want to execute it *once*, and that is after a login via the login_controller.

I tried adding a response header in the login controller:

```
response.headers['user_logged_in'] = "true"
```

and I put my JS in the application.html.erb to check for this header - but the header is not there:

```
if @user && request.headers['user_logged_in'] == "true"
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: The reason the header is not there is because the client receives the redirect response which is basically just a 3XX status code and a location header and then sends a new request for the URI in the location header. The client will not pass your custom header back. Thats what cookies where designed for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your situation is perfect to use [`flash`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html).

Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next action and then cleared out.

So, you can do:

```rb
class SessionsController
  def create
    flash[:signed_in] = true
  end
end
```

Then, in your `application.html.erb` you can do:

```rb
<% if flash[:signed_in] %>
  ...
<% end %>
```